# Undefined variable: page (View: ...\resources\views\layouts\app.blade.php

Tags: laravel, view

A variável não funciona quando entra no login.

na view de login estou injetando o layout:

```
@extends('layouts.app')
```

e no layout tem a variável

```
<p class="num">Telefone: {!!$page->telefone!!}</p>
```

Se estiver acessando as paginas que não passam pelo middleware auth, abre normalmente, mas do contrário a variável não é reconhecida, com o erro:

```
Undefined variable: page (View: ...\resources\views\layouts\app.blade.php)
```

Eu sou novato e não sei como fazer funcionar dentro do middleware?

--controller

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

use App\Page;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PagesController extends Controller
{
    public function welcome(Request $request)
    {
        $page = Page::findOrFail(1);

        return view('welcome', compact('page'));
    }

    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $keyword = $request->get('search');
        $perPage = 25;

        if (!empty($keyword)) {
            $pages = Page::where('titulo', 'LIKE', "%$keyword%")
                ->orWhere('menu', 'LIKE', "%$keyword%")
                ->orWhere('body', 'LIKE', "%$keyword%")
                ->latest()->paginate($perPage);
        } else {
            $pages = Page::latest()->paginate($perPage);
        }
        return view('page.pages.index', compact('pages'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\View\View
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view('page.pages.create');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse|\Illuminate\Routing\Redirector
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {

        $requestData = $request->all();

        Page::create($requestData);

        return redirect('page/pages')->with('flash_message', 'Page added!');
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\View\View
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        $page = Page::findOrFail($id);

        return view('page.pages.show', compact('page'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\View\View
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        $page = Page::findOrFail($id);

        return view('page.pages.edit', compact('page'));
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @param  int  $id
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse|\Illuminate\Routing\Redirector
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {

        $requestData = $request->all();

        $page = Page::findOrFail($id);
        $page->update($requestData);

        return redirect('page/pages')->with('flash_message', 'Page updated!');
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse|\Illuminate\Routing\Redirector
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        Page::destroy($id);

        return redirect('page/pages')->with('flash_message', 'Page deleted!');
    }
}
```

Comment: Coloca o código do seu controller.

Comment: Primeiramente, não tem nada a ver com `middleware` e segundo qual rota está utilizando para acontecer o determinado erro?

Answer (score 0):

Você está tentando utilizar a variável `$page` da view que herda `layouts.app`?

Talvez você passar explicitamente a variável `$page` para o seu layout.

```
@extends('layouts.app', compact('page'))
```